# Django Rest Framework RegexValidators weird error

Tags: python, regex, database, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make fields for github username and linkedin id but the validators are returning 400 no matter what values I input.

```
github_username_validator = validators.RegexValidator(
    r"^[a-zA-Z\d](?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-(?=[a-zA-Z\d]))+$",
    "Enter a valid username.",
    "characters.",
    "invalid",
)

linkedin_id_validator = validators.RegexValidator(
    r"^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$",
    "Enter a valid username.",
    "characters.",
    "invalid",
)
```

Fields:

```
    github_username = models.CharField(
        max_length=39,
        unique=False,
        null=True,
        help_text="Enter a valid username.",
        validators=[github_username_validator, ReservedNameValidator()],
    )

    linkedin_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=71,
        unique=False,
        null=True,
        help_text="Enter a valid LinkedIn ID..",
        validators=[linkedin_id_validator, ReservedNameValidator()],
    )
```

These are the validators. The regexes were both tested and seem to be working. What could be wrong?

I tried removing the validators, and it worked. I also tried removing only the github validator/ linkedin and it worked.
Expected the PATCH to go through